# Excel VBA - How to validate input to be in certain column

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I have a script that asks for a starting cell

```
Set myCell = Application.InputBox( _
prompt:="Choose a starting field", Type:=8)

If myCell = Null Or myCell = "" Or Len(myCell.Value) < 3 Or Len(myCell.Value) > 12 Then
    MsgBox "Incorrect cell value"
    Exit Sub
    Else
```

So, I have these checks for the value of the given cell so the script will not run if the validation does not go through. What I need is also for the validation to check whether the cell in certain column (D in my case).

So I need the validation to say "IS the selected cell in column D?" If Yes, continue, if no stop.

I've relentlessly googled to try to find this kind of comparison but I just fail to give it a good query.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: myCell is a Range object. The Range Object has many properties. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx Among these properties is the Column property.

Comment: @Rich Thanks. I've used myCell.Column <> 4 as a way to tell whether a selected celll is in the column D and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Rich Holton I found the solution.

In order to check whether the input cell is in the column you want it to the following syntax can be used:

```
If myCell.Column <> 4 Then
...
End If
```

Where 4 is equal to Column D in this case. (Column A = 1, Column B = 2 and so on...)